# facing difficulty for reproducing maps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am struggling for several months to reproduce a map that is saved in the folder (codes_that_following) but did not find a solution to make it. I am also sharing the original codes that I want to reproduce for my study area, find the link below;

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yj8ie1qj2w0tutu/AACigc0Qk0wNoUGVHxF1Ly0oa?dl=0

when I run the codes,

```
ggplot(fips_us) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = carbon, geometry = geometry), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = us_outline, aes(geometry = geometry), 
           fill = NA, size = 0.25) + 
    scale_fill_scico(palette = "bilbao") +
    facet_grid(vars(month))
```

it gives me this error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 0 Kb Error during wrapup: memory exhausted (limit reached?) 
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Comment: What's going wrong? Do you get an error message? Or is the map wrong? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: when I run the codes, ##ggplot(fips_us) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = carbon, geometry = geometry), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = us_outline, aes(geometry = geometry), fill = NA, size = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_scico(palette = "bilbao") +
  facet_grid(vars(month))## it gives me this error ##Error: cannot allocate vector of size 0 Kb
Error during wrapup: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart##

Comment: I've edited that comment into the question. This makes the question better. If you have to clarify your question because of comments you can do this with the "Edit" button.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/438771/115

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your code.

1. You are grouping by lat long, and your are not using points to describe the underlying data, but shapes (states), so when you `right_join` with the sf object it creates a new geometry for each lat long. And that is too much.

Solution: grup by state `NAME_1`

2. The geometries themselves are too much detailed. Specially if you showing them from so "far away", it´s just useless information and makes is harder for `ggplot2` to compute.

Solution: use `rmapshaper::ms_simplify` to simplify all the geometries.

Bellow the code and output:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rmapshaper)

# Read in drought data
drought_fips <- readxl::read_xlsx("willdfire_climate_data.xlsx")
chi <- sf::read_sf("gadm36_CHN_1.shp")

# simplify
chi <- rmapshaper::ms_simplify(chi, keep = 0.001)

# Calculate mean DCSI by year and month
month_fips <- drought_fips %>% 
  group_by(year, month, NAME_1) %>% 
  summarise(carbon = mean(fire.carbon))

# Combine with shapefile
fips_chi <- chi %>% 
  right_join(month_fips)

# select a few years and months for example
# stackoverflow has a 2mb limit for images, and your image with all the years and months has to be very large to be properly readable. So in your code use fips_chi and save it with large dimensions in ggsave.
fips_chi2 <- fips_chi %>%  
  filter(year %in% c(2015:2019),
         month %in% c(1:6))
  
# plot
g <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = chi,
          aes(geometry = geometry),
          color = "black",
          fill = "white",
          stroke = 0.1) +   
  geom_sf(data = fips_chi2,
          aes(fill = carbon, 
              geometry = geometry),
          stroke = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(labels = scales::number_format(scale = 1e-3),
                       name = "Carbon\nthousands") +
  facet_grid(year ~ month) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'),
        axis.line = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines")) +
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 1, barheight = 12))


g
# save plot
ggsave(filename = "Carbon9.png", 
       height = 8, 
       width = 12)
```

I belive you be able to further customize this example to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am not looking for this kind of map. I have also added a map in the folder that I am looking for in my study area.

Comment: @alihassan you should try to be as clear as possible on what is your goal. There is several images on the folder, some of them are similar to the above. You can edit the original question to be more specific. You are able to insert images as well here in stackoverflow! I can only guess what you want at this point (my guess is: you have a lot of data points and want some sort of spatial interpolation of those points over time, there are several, see https://rspatial.org/raster/analysis/4-interpolation.html). But my guess might be wrong and working on an aswer, as fun as that can be, pointless.